# Drupal single user, multiple civicrm memberships, editable details: What's a good logical approach to integrating them?

Tags: drupal, civimember, profile

Drupal 7 site, and each Drupal user could have more than one civicrm 'membership'. 
Each membership is for a business and 
each business with a 'type1' membership is entitled to a listing on a directory node (public) in drupal with filters.

What would be a good approach, as ideally it would be good if users (contacts) can log into Drupal and edit each membership's details (for the listing) from their one Drupal contact account?

OK, so I can create a profile to be pulled into each Drupal user. But I can't display different 'profile' types on the same user?? So how do I pull profiles for each business, of that contact, back to their Drupal account for them to edit/maintain?

I understand it involves various components re edit forms and membership forms etc. but I want to get the wireframe layout right before building a range of webforms etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your membership type so that it provides an 'inherited membership' via the 'employee for' relationship, then the Employee will have a permissioned relationship over the Business, and can therefore access the address details etc for the Organisation via their Contact Dashboard.
Secondly if they are logged in then the employee (or primary contact or whatever you need it to be) can have 'permission' on a webform to update more details about the Organisation if you can't give them enough access to fields via Contact Dashboard.
Does that move you towards your goal?

Comment: brill, makes sense, and what I needed Thanks. I just got my head done in going through the workbook and employee of and employer for ...